# How to zoom out Android designer view in Intellij Idea12?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, zooming, scale, designer

I am trying new Intellij Idea 12 for Android development.

I've sucessfully imported all my eclipse projects but I still can't figure out how to zoom out the designer view?

I have troubles with XHDPI layouts on my laptop resolution.

Comment: Are you saying that the zoom in/out buttons are not working?

Comment: Don't the **+** and **-** buttons work?

Comment: I don't see any zoom buttons in toolbar or top menus. Ctrl + +/- won't work, Ctrl + mouse scroll won' work, also pressing +/- keys won't work. (Windows and Linux versions)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't configure that too, but I could find a better solution, at least for me:

There is a `Preview` tab on the right side of the IDE, when you are in XML text mode.

After clicking you can watch your layout changing dynamically as soon as you make edits, and also you can zoom in/out from there.

Hopefully, they will fix this in upcoming updates.

[This](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-layout-preview-tool-window.html) article helped me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android UI Designer in IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have any zoom options, it always displays in 1:1 scale for the chosen device resolution. Zoom feature is available only for the **Preview** (when you are editing layout XML code manually and **Preview** is displayed in a tool window).

I didn't find this feature requested, so you are welcome to [submit a new ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).